# How can I tell emacs not to break long lines?

Tags: emacs

How can I set Emacs to not automatically break long lines?

I find it easier to visualize indentation without its breaking long lines, to instead use horizontal scrolling when needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried

`M-x toggle-truncate-lines`

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to remove ["fill-mode"](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoFillMode) ?

```
M-x auto-fill-mode
```

Comment: auto-fill-mode dont works to me but toggle-truncate-lines works. Thanks.